# ReactJS: How to create a multi-page website?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've started learning ReactJS and I am wondering how to add multiple pages to my site. I have my project and a basic navbar set up. Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add as many pages in your react app as you wish. But for navigation from one page to other like for example from home or default page to about page you need the help of a package known as **react-router-dom**. Version 6 is preferable. By using **react-router-dom**, with the help of **BrowserRouter**, **Routes**, **Route**, **Link** and **to** methods, you can navigate from one page to your next page.

Checkout :
https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/getting-started/overview
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UjHT_NKR_gU